# How to scale in Edit Mode after scaling to Zero

Tags: mesh, scale

I was working on *Shape Keys* when I discovered that an *Object* cannot be *Scale* back after scaling to Zero in **Edit Mode**.

I pressed <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> to scale to 0 in **Edit Mode**

Then when I tried to press <kbd>S</kbd> again to scale it back in **Edit Mode** it doesn't have any effect.

Am using 2.79b, and I've tried it on 2.80, same result.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image: resize mesh]

After pressing <kbd>S</kbd> in **Edit Mode**, I immediately press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and set the *Scale* parameters in the *Resize Panel*

Comment: As far as I can tell, they have already done the scaling and are trying to deal with a zero scale mesh.

Comment: That is misleading. If an object's geometry is scaled to 0 in edit mode, all the vertices share the exact same location and the information is lost. There is no way to scale it back to what it was. This 'solution' is only adjusting last operation - it's pretty much the same as undo and after another operation is performed that will not work any more. The answer is incorrect and may mislead someone who is new to Blender and stumbles upon it.

Comment: @Martin Z Is not the same thing as *undo* try it yourself and see what am talking about.

Comment: The functionality is called Redo Last. You can also call the the Redo Last panel with F6. It only works for the very last operation immediately after it is performed. Try scaling geometry to 0, then deselect all and select all again. After another scale operation you can enter whatever values you wish into Redo Last panel and it will not bring your mesh back.

Comment: I agree with you if you didn't you didn't agree with me. Because am not a professional, that's why am asking. But I don't understand why someone will be **down voting** the answer I gave to my question when the person could not give a better solution